# Why is only padding-top and padding-left working when the padding set is small

Tags: css, padding

I just start learning CSS, so my question is very basic.
Like in the picture, if set padding: 10px; of it, but in the outcome, seems like only top and left working, why's that happen, I mean if with the workflow, is it should be the last two bottom and left working?

[image]

Comment: All of your paddings work, you just don't see it because container is too large

Comment: you have any code to share

Comment: Inspect the element and go to computed section and verify

Comment: try using `padding: 10px !important;`

Comment: Please provide your code snippet

Answer (score 0):

your container is long so that's why `botton` and `right` padding not see

if you want to give padding from `bottom` and `right` also so many ways

```
padding-top
padding-right
padding-bottom
padding-left
```

//for example

```
padding: 25px 50px 75px 100px;

top padding is 25px
right padding is 50px
bottom padding is 75px
left padding is 100px
```

Comment: That's what I want to figure out, why only top and right can be seen when the container is way larger than content and padding set. Why not bottom and left.

Comment: b'cause its start from top and left

Answer (score 0):

If im not wrong this is what you are trying to do

```css
.wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
}
.content{
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    some content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I want to know if the container is larger than the actual content, after set a small padding, why only can see top and left padding, not any other side.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also got the same issue. after setting the box-sizing property to border-box the issue is solved.

```
.container{
  padding:25px 15px;
  box-sizing:border-box
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using the code snippet and if does not work then try using `!important`

```css
.container{
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  border:5px solid #000;
  padding:50px;
}
.box{
  height:20px;
  width:80px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  float:left;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="box">
This is box
</div>
</div>
```